# Email forwarding from outlook.com to Gmail not working for all messages

Tags: gmail, outlook.com, email-forwarding

Some important email messages are not getting forwarded.

Is there some kind of block that does not allow forwarding of emails with 'sensitive' information?

Or does outlook.com make mistakes?

Comment: Did you check your Gmail spam bucket?

Comment: I am having the same problem lots of emails to `name@domain.tld` forwarded to `myname@outlook.com` have not been received. my webserver's mail trace is showing them as `delivered`.

Comment: Has the issue been resolved for you? or are you still having problems?